# Does .Net Core 2.2 HttpClient remember failed DNS lookups?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dns

We are deploying a web application to an internally hosted windows kubernetes cluster. Through a mechanism I don't fully understand (but I don't believe is relevant to the question), after deployment to the K8s cluster our application is addressable by a DNS entry that includes that name and version number of the application.

As such, the exact DNS value is not created until the deployment is complete. And in fact, it takes a little while after the deployment is complete before it is addressable.

Now to the .Net Core HttpClient question...

(And in case it is relevant, the code in question is running on Windows Server 2012 via Team City)

I have written some code using .Net Core 2.2 HttpClient (via HttpClientFactory) to poll the healthcheck endpoint of the application to know when the deployment is complete. At present it waits a period of time before making any requests. It then polls periodically for a while (up to 5 minutes) before giving up.

The issue I'm having is that if the first polling request happens before the DNS entry is available it (rightly) fails with a 'no such host is known' exception. But all further requests will also fail with the same exception.

The sweet spot in my case seems to be to wait three minutes. When doing this the first request to my application will succeed and all is good. But if I only wait two minutes, it will fail, and keep failing even if I keep trying for another 5 minutes. To me it looks like once the first DNS fails, I'm doomed.

Strangely I have found that once my polling fails enough and gives up, a subsequent call to nslookup succeeds (from powershell - i.e. separate to the .Net Core console application). But then more code is executed, this time running .Net Framework 4.6 code... and it too has problems with the DNS.

So could I be correct that a DNS failure is remembered somewhere, even if it not across the board (as evidenced by the nslookup success)? And if so, how can the DNS lookup be forced to be retried?

I have tried setting PooledConnectionIdleTimeout and PooledConnectionLifetime values for the SocketsHttpHandler in question (to 20 seconds, as my pause between retries is 30 seconds), but that has not helped. But even if they were the answer and I've done something wrong with it, that wouldn't explain why a separate .Net process running straight after has the same issue.